# VBA - Workbook as variable in the formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a VBA code that inserts vlookup formula. The line looks like that:

```
Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[Cash.xlsm]Account Mapping'!C3,1,0)"
```

However, I would like to make it more general in case someone changes the name of the main file where the source for vlookup is.

I defined variables path and mainwb:

```
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
mainwb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

but got lost while updating the formula in the code with them.

Tried something like:

```
Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'path & [mainwb]Account Mapping'!C3,1,0)"
```

But unfortunately, I haven't succeed so far.

Can you please support?

Comment: General rule of thumb: variables don't belong inside quotes, and need concatenated with `&`. So something like `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & path & "[" & mainwb & "]Account Mapping'!C3,1,0)"`.

Comment: Another helpful hint: before writing the formula to a cell, use `Debug.Print` to print it to the Immediate Window to make sure it's what you want.